# How many cameras i can use by pygame.camera?

Tags: python, camera, pygame

How many cameras i can use by pygame.camera in the same time?

I try to use 3 web cameras, but program doesn't work! When i'm using one or two web cameras - it's ok. =\

There is my code:

```
# import the relevant libraries
import time
import sys
import pygame
import pygame.camera
from pygame.locals import *
from pygame.tests.base_test import pygame_quit
pygame.init()

s_width = 645
s_height = 600
width = 640
height = 480

class detectCameras(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.camera.init()

class webCamera(object):

    def __init__(self,cam_number,cam_resolution=[640,480],color_mode="RGB"):
        self.cam_number = cam_number
        self.cam_resolution = cam_resolution
        self.color_mode = color_mode
        self.cam = pygame.camera.Camera(self.cam_number,self.cam_resolution,self.color_mode)

    def start(self):
        self.cam.start()

    def stop(self):
        self.cam.stop()

    def get_b(self):
        return self.cam.get_buffer()

    def get_image(self, new_width = 320, new_height = 240):
        self.img = self.cam.get_image()
        self.new_width = new_width
        self.new_height = new_height
        self.img = pygame.transform.scale(self.img, (self.new_width,self.new_height))
        return self.img

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([s_width,s_height])
# set window title
pygame.display.set_caption("OMS CCTV")
# set icon
pygame.display.set_icon(pygame.image.load('icon.png').convert_alpha())


#detectCameras()
pygame.camera.init()
# set up a camera object

cam_on = webCamera(1) #pygame.camera.Camera(1,[width,height],"RGB")
cam_tw = webCamera(2)
cam_tr = webCamera(3)
# start the camera

cam_on.start()
cam_tw.start()
cam_tr.start()
#
mainloop = 1
while mainloop:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            mainloop = 0
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit("Exit")
        elif event.type == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            mainloop = 0
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit("Exit")
    # sleep between every frame
    time.sleep( 0.05 )


    screen.fill([0,0,0])

    image_on = cam_on.get_image()
    screen.blit( image_on, ( 0, 0 ) )


    image_tw = cam_tw.get_image()
    screen.blit( image_tw, ( 325, 0 ) )


    image_tr = cam_tr.get_image()
    screen.blit( image_tr, ( 0, 245 ) )

    pygame.display.update()
```

I don't know why it's doesn't work!

Comment: Call `pygame.camera.list_cameras()` and get the camera names and see if perhaps the numbering of the cameras is simply not `1`, `2`, `3` or if there aren't 3 cameras listed.

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/camera.html) for `pygame.camera`:

> EXPERIMENTAL!: This api may change or disappear in later `pygame` releases. If you use this, your code will very likely break with the next `pygame` release.

I don't think you can rely on it supporting any particular number of cameras; perhaps two is the best it will manage.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into the same problem. Unfortunately a USB2 host controller can only handle the bandwidth of 2 uncompressed 640x480 streams. If you want to use more cameras, you have to make sure you have more than one host controller in the computer, and that a max of 2 are plugged into each one.

You could also lower the resolution you are requesting from the cameras.